# Selenium Python Not Working In Google Colab

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-colaboratory

I used below code on google colab and installed selenium package

```
# !pip install selenium
# !apt-get update # to update ubuntu to correctly run apt install
# !apt install chromium-chromedriver
# !cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
wd.get("https://pooya.um.ac.ir/gateway/PuyaAuthenticate.php")
```

And just loading for a while and not working at all..!!
How can i fix it to access any website?

Comment: I tested your code in Colab with ```wd.get("https://google.com")``` and everything worked fine. The problem may be coming from the website you are trying to access.

Comment: @Agudolive Does it work for given link in above?

Comment: Nope, with your link it doesn’t work for me. But with ```google.com``` it works fine, so the problem is not from Selenium or Google Colab.

Answer (score 0):

The following function works
!apt... is the important part for using Selenium in Google Colab.

```
!apt update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!pip install selenium

from selenium import webdriver

def driversetup():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    #run Selenium in headless mode
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    #overcome limited resource problems
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument("lang=en")
    #open Browser in maximized mode
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    #disable infobars
    options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
    #disable extension
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    options.add_argument("--incognito")
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)    

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined});")

    return driver

driver = driversetup()
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).